# Calculating the simplicial homology of a tetrahedron.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, cw-complexes, simplicial-stuff

I want to calculate the simplicial homology of the $\Delta$-complex figure on the right:

> [image]

I believe that it consists of $2$ 0-simplices, four $1$-simplices and three $2$-simplices. So I am now in the step of the simplicial homology groups:

1-  $H_0^{\Delta}(M) = \frac{\operatorname{Ker}\partial_0}{\operatorname{Im}\partial_1}  \cong \mathbb Z$.

Also, it is clear that  $\operatorname{Ker}\partial_1 \cong \mathbb Z,$ therefore

2-  $H_1^{\Delta}(M) = \frac{\operatorname{Ker}\partial_1}{\operatorname{Im}\partial_2} \cong \frac{\langle a \rangle}{\langle -a + b - c, -a + d -c, -d -a +b  \rangle}$  **but then I think I have to use SNF to complete it, but I am not sure how to do this, could someone help me in this please?**

3- $H_2^{\Delta}(K) = \frac{\operatorname{Ker}\partial_2}{\operatorname{Im}\partial_3} \cong \frac{\{0\}}{\{0\}} \cong 0$ as $\Delta_n(K) \cong \{0\}$ for $n \geq 3.$

also, $H_n^{\Delta}(K) \cong 0$ for $n \geq 3.$

**Are my simplicial homology groups (other than H_1) correct?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation the simplices you have from the geometry generate the groups in the chain complex and $\partial_i$ are linear maps between.
Therefore, choosing an ordering for each of these generating sets allows you to write $\partial_i$ as matrices, so the problem is reduced to standard linear algebra.

For example, let's call $A,B,C$ the vertices of the original triangle, that are sent to the same point, and $P$ the point in the middle.
Then  $C_0(M)$ is generate by $\{A,P\}$ (taken in this order),
$C_1(M)$ is generate by $\{[A,B],[A,P],[B,P],[C,P]\}$, and finally $C_2(M)$ is generate by $\{[A,B,P],[B,C,P],[C,A,P]\}$.

Your computations, except $H_1$ are indeed correct, but you should justify that $\ker \partial_2=0$.

$\ker\partial_1$ is wrong and you can tell it already because you know that $\operatorname{Im}\partial_2\subset \ker\partial_1$.
Indeed, using the basis choosen above we get
$\partial_2=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1& 1\\
-1 & 0& 1\\
1 & -1& 0\\
0 & 1& -1
\end{pmatrix}$ and
$ \partial_1=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$.

Therefore $\ker \partial_1=\left<\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
-1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0\\
-1\\
\end{pmatrix}\right>$.

Now you need to actually compute the quotient, for example using Smith Normal Form.